# Kerberos | Keytab | Unable to obtain password from user

Tags: hadoop, hive, kerberos

I am new to Kerberos/hive, want to connect hive (Kerberos implemented) using JDBC.

> > org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration conf = new
> >     org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration();
> >                 conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "Kerberos");
> >                 UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
> >                 UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("", "");
> >
> > Class.forName(Util.getConstantProperty("hive.class.name"));
> >
> > log.info("Making connection with Hive DB"); hiveConn =
> >     DriverManager.getConnection("",,"hive.user","");

getting error:

```
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user

        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(UserGroupInformation.java:935)
```

Note: krb5.conf is available under java-security path

Comment: Manually create `keytabs`. I specified the `url` as comment in the other question.

Comment: As per devops team they are able to login to same Keytab file.    In java verified using f.canRead() that keytab file is accessible.

Comment: That is strange in indeed.